# Embed Twitter Timeline on Android Phonegap HTML5

Tags: android, html, twitter, cordova

I already use embed code provided by Twitter example as below. When I trying to run it on Android Phonegap application, the timeline doesn't show on the devices, but it show on the esclipse browser. Please assist. TQ. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [this](https://github.com/k-rudy/phonegap-twitter-timeline) simple service. It works fine for me on iOS and Android versions on PhoneGap 3.1.0